# How to compute Net Reclassification Improvement or Alternatives?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, statistical-significance, predictive-models, metric

I am working on a binary classification problem with ~5k records and class proportion of 33:67.

I have 60 features/variables in my dataset and finally I have come to about 10 variables based on multiple feature selection algorithms and domain understanding.

Now I would like to experiment with this 10 features and get the best of these 10 which gives the high performance.

For example, Having 6 features might give an AUC of 84% whereas adding one new feature (7 features) might give an AUC of 85%.

But adding two features (8 features), might give an AUC of 83%.

I read in several posts and F Harrel blog posts that AUC is not always a good metric to compare model performance.

I did refer several other posts in this forum where they discuss that `Accuracy` is not the best metric and so on but as a beginner, those discussions go beyond what I can digest (which I will definitely learn over time) but currently can you help me with the below

q1) So what are other best metrics that should be used and how to do this in Python?

q2) How to calculate Net Reclassification Improvement using Python? Read it's better than AUC.

Can you people please help me?

Comment: This might be a bit late but there is a working python example below. https://lambertleong.medium.com/area-under-the-curve-and-beyond-f87a8ec6937b?source=friends_link&sk=0e6708e789b333b55b5bd32302bd2736